# bxSlider javascript escape ' syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#slider-comingsoon').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  pagerCustom: '#slider-comingsoon-pager',
  nextSelector: '#slider-comingsoon-next',
  nextText: '<img src="../images/box-rightarrow-hd.png" height="34px" width="27px" onmouseover="this.src='../images/box-rightarrow-hd-rollover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='../images/box-rightarrow-hd.png';" />'
 });
});
```

How do I escape the following line correctly so that it works?

```
  nextText: '<img src="../images/box-rightarrow-hd.png" height="34px" width="27px" onmouseover="this.src='../images/box-rightarrow-hd-rollover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='../images/box-rightarrow-hd.png';" />'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\'` instead of `'`

```
nextText: '<img src="../images/box-rightarrow-hd.png" height="34px" width="27px" onmouseover="this.src=\'../images/box-rightarrow-hd-rollover.png\';" onmouseout="this.src=\'../images/box-rightarrow-hd.png\';" />'
```

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, but oddly it is not working. It has to do with this line since once I commented it out the jQuery plugin works fine.

Comment: +1 That is the correct answer @alchuang. Check the fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/qMctW/

Comment: It turns out that it works! Mistake on my part. Thanks again! :)